# Presenting ActionSheet Alert on UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uialertcontroller

I have custom `CollectionViewCell` called `DiaryCell` in my project. I configure my cells using that class. Each cell has this menu button, and when it's clicked I want `UICollectionviewcontroller` to present actionsheet, but it gives me the following error.

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
```

Here is the code to handle that action when menu button is pressed in the cell. This action is handled in UICollectionViewController. To sum it up, my tap gesture is defined in customCell and when tapped it redirects the code to controller to handle the actions.

```
    func menuButtonPressed(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {


    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
    let editAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Edit", style: .default) { (action) in

    }
    let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { (action) in

    }

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Pick Your Adventure ", message: "You have the following options", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(editAction)
    alert.addAction(deleteAction)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I believe it has something to do with view layers. Since a cell is tapped inside `UICollectionview`, it doesn't know how and where to present actionsheet. I could be wrong. Thank you for reading my question.

EDIT: Code responsible for redirection of action to controller.

```
    var homeCollection = HomeCollectionViewController()

    let menuImageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "menu_image")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

    func setUpMenuItemGesture() {
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.homeCollection, action: #selector(self.homeCollection.menuButtonPressed(_:)))
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    tapGesture.delegate = homeCollection
    menuImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}
```

CODE FOR LAYOUT IN MY `UICollectionViewController`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = collectionView.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: width + (width*(0.15)))
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Add the code that "redirects the code to controller".  That's probably where the issue is.

Comment: @dan Thanks for responding to my question. I have edited my code.

Comment: @Xcoder123 I have size for layout and everything else working, it only gives me error when I present action sheet.

Comment: So, when you attempt to present the Action Sheet, your collection view layout goes nil... Try using **self.present**, so that the collection view will present the action sheet itself. If this doesn't work, I have no idea what may be wrong here

Comment: @Xcoder123 I have already tried that, still didn't work. I have no clue what's going on. Let me post my code for layout, so you can see if there is anything wrong with that.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue why that is happening

Comment: @Xcoder123 Does my layout code look okay?

Comment: Yes it does. I am trying to figure that out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134711/discussion-between-xcoder123-and-vandan-a-patel).

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is this line:

```
var homeCollection = HomeCollectionViewController()
```

That causes a completely new, separate HomeCollectionViewController to be created. It was never properly initialized and thus is invalid; more important, it is not the HomeCollectionViewController you want. You want a reference to the *existing* HomeCollectionViewController that you are already using, not a *new and different* HomeCollectionViewController.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for your response. Would you like to suggest how should I go about solving this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I don't know where your existing HomeCollectionViewController is, in the vast view controller hierarchy of your app. Only _you_ know that. The class that contains this code _must_ have _some_ relationship to that existing HomeCollectionViewController; you must _use_ the nature of that relationship to _get a reference_ to it. I talk about the problem and show a solution in one particular case in this section of my Swift book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#SECinstanceRefs

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just curious, when we say self.present(), would't it figure out which HomeCollectionViewController we are referring to.

Comment: If my guess is right about what the problem is, the new unconfigured irrelevant HomeCollectionViewController is the one saying `self.present` and that's the problem.

Comment: I see. Let me think it through, and try new things based on your suggestions. Thanks. I will keep you posted.

Comment: I must say your post was something which I could have never figured out on my own for ages. Just one question though, through keyWidonw, you can get rootViewContrller, I am not sure how can i get a particular viewController's instance (in my case, HomeCollectionViewController)

Comment: So you're asking how to get from the collection cell to the collection view controller? I think the way I would do it is to walk up the responder chain looking for the first view controller I come to. But, as I said, there are probably other ways to get there, depending on where the collection view controller is in the view controller hierarchy.

Comment: I meant to ask how to get the reference to HomeViewController. This one (let vc = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) gives reference to rootViewController.